# Electronic component for tapping

Tags: microcontroller, components

I'm in need of electronic component that is able to be tapping, giving a type of massage on the skin. I did some search and can't find anything that is as big as the tip of the finger with the nail.
Do you know about something? I'm thinking of using some type of ATTiny controller to control the rhythm and the sequences. I was thinking of some electromagnetic type of a pump or servo that could be used but didn't find anything.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: A vibrator?  What about the things that shake your cell phone.

Comment: lol, good idea. I'll check it out.

Comment: For those voting to close, I think this is one of those items that is very difficult to search for if you don't know the key words. I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One very useful keyword/phrase you could use for searches is "haptic actuator". Haptics includes both vibration motors and resonant actuators used for tactile feedback. [This](http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sszb151/sszb151.pdf?DCMP=hpa-aip-hap-awire&HQS=hpa-aip-hap-awire-20140711-haptics-mc-en) is a good TI application note on it.

[image]

From the same supplier, a typical pager motor:

[image: http://www.precisionmicrodrives.com/tech-blog/2011/12/12/vibration-motors-used-in-haptic-feedback-for-stroke-rehabilitation]

Comment: isn't this the same as vibrating motor used for cell-phones?

Comment: It doesn't rotate so I wouldn't call it a motor (maybe a resonant linear motor?). Closer to a subwoofer (but narrow band). Large ones are sometimes used to rattle chairs (and thus the people in them). The cell phone thing is usually a DC motor with an eccentric weight attached to the end of the shaft (see photo above).

Comment: how strong are the linear actuators? Is it comparable to finger tapping?

Comment: Very similar I think. Diameter is 10mm (smaller than my index finger tip), acceleration is 1g p-p with a 100g test load. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_%28electronics%29) data sheet for example (no endorsement of this supplier is implied).

Comment: great, do you know where I can get it in USA?

Comment: No, but I think you can easily search for this kind of product now.

Answer (score 4):

I think a small enclosed vibration motor will suit your needs. This type is ~ 10 mm diameter, 2mm thick.

[image]

The drawing in Spehro's answer made me curious, because the thingy he shows is looks a lot like the motor I have, so I dissected one. Conclusion: the motor I showed is definitely a rotating type, not a pulsing type.

Answer (score 3):

You would want a solenoid.  A solenoid pulls or pushes the actuator shaft in or out when you energize (apply current to) the solenoid coil.

If the shaft is too thin you can put a rubber or plastic cap on it.

[Look here for some examples of what I'm talking about.](http://www.kgs-america.com/ca.html) I'm sure you can find more suppliers now that you know what you are looking for.

I used the search terms solenoid and braille to find that address.

On further search, I see that Sparkfun also sells a 5Volt solenoid with a 4 to 6 millimeter throw.

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot! I might try to use the vibration motor but your answer is actually what I was asking for...